# Django: Get the second user object

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

So I have this model objects in my project [model objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAIX9.jpg) each one of the objects has this data on it [this data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NCYm.jpg), what I need is to get the second user that is save in the objects. I am new in django so I dont know how to do it, but is this something to queryset?, and how can I get the second user in my views?.

Here is my code:
models.py

```
from django.db import models

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Q


class ThreadManager(models.Manager):
    def by_user(self, user):
        qlookup = Q(first=user) | Q(second=user)
        qlookup2 = Q(first=user) & Q(second=user)
        qs = self.get_queryset().filter(qlookup).exclude(qlookup2).distinct()
        return qs

    def get_or_new(self, user, other_username): # get_or_create
        username = user.username
        if username == other_username:
            return None
        qlookup1 = Q(first__username=username) & Q(second__username=other_username)
        qlookup2 = Q(first__username=other_username) & Q(second__username=username)
        qs = self.get_queryset().filter(qlookup1 | qlookup2).distinct()
        if qs.count() == 1:
            return qs.first(), False
        elif qs.count() > 1:
            return qs.order_by('timestamp').first(), False
        else:
            Klass = user.__class__
            user2 = Klass.objects.get(username=other_username)
            if user != user2:
                obj = self.model(
                        first=user, 
                        second=user2
                    )
                obj.save()
                return obj, True
            return None, False


class Thread(models.Model):
    first        = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='chat_thread_first')
    second       = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='chat_thread_second')
    updated      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    objects      = ThreadManager()

    @property
    def room_group_name(self):
        return f'chat_{self.id}'

    def broadcast(self, msg=None):
        if msg is not None:
            broadcast_msg_to_chat(msg, group_name=self.room_group_name, user='admin')
            return True
        return False


class ChatMessage(models.Model):
    thread      = models.ForeignKey(Thread, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    user        = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name='sender', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    message     = models.TextField()
    timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponseForbidden
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views.generic.edit import FormMixin

from django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView

from .forms import ComposeForm
from .models import Thread, ChatMessage


class ThreadView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormMixin, DetailView):
    template_name = 'chat/thread.html'
    form_class = ComposeForm
    success_url = './'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Thread.objects.by_user(self.request.user)

    def get_object(self):
        other_username  = self.kwargs.get("username")
        obj, created    = Thread.objects.get_or_new(self.request.user, other_username)
        if obj == None:
            raise Http404
        return obj

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = self.get_form()
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        thread = self.get_object()
        user = self.request.user
        message = form.cleaned_data.get("message")
        ChatMessage.objects.create(user=user, thread=thread, message=message)
        return super().form_valid(form)


# Messages view
def Messages(request, *args, **kwargs):
    Chats = Thread.objects.by_user(request.user)
    other_user = Thread
    context = {
        'content': Chats,
        'other_user': other_user
    }
    return render(request, "chat/messages.html", context)
```

as you can see I want to put in the context of this function

```
def Messages(request, *args, **kwargs):
```

the second user in the variable of the other_user,
does anybody know how to do it? thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple way to get the second object, instead of other_user variable in your views you only need the context "content", and in your template just make a loop:

```
{% for chat in content %}
   {{ chat.second }}
{% endfor %}
```

We are using chat.second to get all the second object of your chat objects.